# TypeError: callback() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prevent_initial_call'

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

While running the following code from Plotly Dash documentation [page](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#prevent-callbacks-from-being-executed-on-initial-load), for Prevent Callbacks From Being Executed on Initial Load, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: callback() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prevent_initial_call'
```

Here is the code

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
from datetime import datetime
import time

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("execute callbacks", id="button_2"),
        html.Div(children="callback not executed", id="first_output_2"),
        html.Div(children="callback not executed", id="second_output_2"),
        html.Div(children="callback not executed", id="third_output_2"),
        html.Div(children="callback not executed", id="fourth_output_2"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("first_output_2", "children"),
    Output("second_output_2", "children"),
    Input("button_2", "n_clicks"), prevent_initial_call=True)
def first_callback(n):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return ["in the first callback it is " + current_time, "in the first callback it is " + current_time]


@app.callback(
    Output("third_output_2", "children"), Input("second_output_2", "children"), prevent_initial_call=True)
def second_callback(n):
    time.sleep(2)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return "in the second callback it is " + current_time


@app.callback(
    Output("fourth_output_2", "children"),
    Input("first_output_2", "children"),
    Input("third_output_2", "children"), prevent_initial_call=True)
def third_output(n, m):
    time.sleep(2)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return "in the third callback it is " + current_time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Python version: 3.6
Dash version: 1.10.0

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prevent_initial_call` keyword argument was [added in Dash 1.12.0](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-v1-12-0-release-pattern-matching-callbacks-fixes-shape-drawing-new-datatable-conditional-formatting-options-prevent-initial-call-and-more/38867), hence you should upgrade to this version or newer.